# Installing Docker within a Docker container => D-Bus connection error

Tags: docker, dockerfile, dbus

I have the following in a Dockerfile:

```
RUN sudo apt-get install -y docker-ce
RUN sudo systemctl start docker
```

When I build the image, I get this output:

```
Step 14/43 : RUN sudo apt-get install -y docker-ce
 ---> Using cache
 ---> b1a8830d0596
Step 15/43 : RUN sudo systemctl start docker
 ---> Running in eff2d9d01762
Failed to get D-Bus connection: Unknown error -1
The command '/bin/sh -c sudo systemctl start docker' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

anyone know what this D-Bus connection error is about?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? To install Docker inside Docker?

Comment: yeah that's right..I learned about the Docker image called "docker:dind", so I have been trying to use that instead of the above. "dind" meaning "docker in docker".

Comment: For what purpose you want dind? For CI\CD? As there is already an image on the [hub](https://hub.docker.com/_/docker/) for this.

Comment: thanks, can you add an answer on how to use the docker image itself? that would be helpful other people and would get you an upvote, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Pull the Docker image from the Docker hub as `docker image pull docker` and you will get an image with Docker pre-installed. It is important to note that you have to mount **docker.sock* as volume to the container like:

`docker container run --rm -it -v /var/run/:/var/run docker`

As this image does not come with a Docker Daemon itself. You have to mount your host's daemon as volume to the container so you can access sibling containers rather the child containers. This avoids the need to install Docker yourself inside the image and works well with Container CI\CD (such as Jenkins inside Docker) too.